# Is there a way to keep two functions in sync?

Tags: java, function, coding-style

I have two functions `A` and `B`.  They do the same thing except one of them does it at a more granular level.  I need to make sure that they are doing the same logic forever, that is, if the functionality of one function changes then the other function should change as well.

The best solution (i think) would be to make a general function and a specific function.  Then have one function call the other.  However, in this case it would require too much code refactoring and for the sake of argument suppose its impossible.

Is there a mechanism that allows me to say, when anything inside this code signature changes make sure you alert the user to look at the other function?

**Edit #1 @Charles Wood**: I'm looking for a mechanism to do this detection to the source code (with annotations or something.)  But alternatives that achieve the same goal are good too.

Comment: It is probable that you can abstract the common logic in a way that it can be written once and invoked by both functions.  However, without a real example we really can't help. Your question is not answerable except in a very general way unless we can see a specific example.  The idea of enforcing this with comments is a non-starter.

Comment: You are correct that if I put specific code someone could give me a specific answer, but without code I still pose a reasonable question and TWO solutions. You also provide a valid/similar solution.  I think the community could help with the problem as-is.

Comment: Are you talking about changes to the function at runtime or edits to the source?

Comment: Good point, I was originally talking about the source.  But I suppose if it could be done at runtime during continuous integration or something that would work too.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
class A {
 public void func() {
   /*some general logic, that you can change further*/
 } 
}
class B extends A {
  @Override
  public void func() {
   super.func();
   /*additional logic_1*/
  }
}

class C extends A {
  @Override
  public void func() {
     super.func();
     /*additional logic_2*/
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
A a1 = new B();
A a2 = new C();
```

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to the solution outlined in the question I'm going to do the following:

- Write a unit test that uses the same data on both functions to ensure that they produce the same results.
- Comment both of the functions and say "hey, look to this **other function** if you change **this function**."

This still isn't perfect though.  If new functionality is introduced to one function, it may not necessarily break the unit test, and the new author may not read my comments that tell them to look at the other function.